# How to change the max size of the u-boot environment?

Tags: linux

I've thought it would be simply changing the CONFIG_ENV_SIZE in the u-boot source along with changing the size in the userspace /etc/fw_env.config to match, but this is not the case.

Comment: Use of CONFIG_ENV_SIZE depends on the medium you specify for storing the environment.  *"[T]his is not the case"* is a useless summary.

Comment: -Tegra TX1, and the failure was that the crc would always fail in the userspace, but not in uboot interactive mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

In order to update the environment size with flash memory (in particular on the Tegra), we need to:

- Ensure the `CONFIG_FILE` is defined in /tools/env/fw_env.h in uboot src (make sure this line
  is uncommented (#define CONFIG_FILE     "/etc/fw_env.config")
- Change `CONFIG_ENV_SIZE` to desired size (/include/configs/tegra-common.h in uboot src), note it
  needs be 4k aligned for flash if using mmc
- Match Env. size below to the size of `CONFIG_ENV_SIZE`
- Set the Device offset below to ((end of environment addr + 1) - `CONFIG_ENV_SIZE`)
  (turns out uboot environment is stored at the end of the boot partition)
- Keep Flash sector size below set to 0x2000 if Env. size differs

Comment: this is all if using userspace fw_printenv tool